# value of $ \int_0^\pi \int_0 ^\pi \vert \cos(x+y)\vert dxdy$

Tags: integration, analysis

value of $$ \int_0^\pi \int_0 ^\pi \vert \cos(x+y)\vert dxdy$$

I use the transformation: $x+y=u $ and $ y=v$, then the above integral becomes

$$ \int_{v=0}^\pi \int_{u=v} ^{\pi+v} \vert \cos(u)\vert dudv$$

after that how to do?, Please help

Comment: Isn't $|\cos|$ $\pi$-periodic?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown, yes , But how make use of the fact , please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the integral $\int_{u=v} ^{\pi+v} \vert \cos(u)\vert du$. Just split it up in $\int_{u=v} ^{\pi} \vert \cos(u)\vert du + \int_{u=\pi} ^{\pi+v} \vert \cos(u)\vert du$. Since $|\cos(x)|$ is $\pi$-periodic, the second part will be equal to $\int_{u=0} ^{v} \vert \cos(u)\vert du$. Therefore $\int_{u=v} ^{\pi+v} \vert \cos(u)\vert du = \int_{u=0} ^{\pi} \vert \cos(u)\vert du = \int_{u=0} ^{\pi} \cos(u) du$.

Comment: How to get $\int_{v=0}^\pi \int_{u=v} ^{\pi+v} \vert \cos(u)\vert dudv$ by changing variables

Comment: How limit of $u$ is from v to $\pi +v$. Can it be said from the fig ?