# HOw to convert $\int_0^\pi \int_0^\pi |cos(x+y)|dxdy$ using the substitution $x=u-v, y=v$.

Tags: integration, surface-integrals

How to convert $I=\int_0^\pi \int_0^\pi |cos(x+y)|dxdy$ to $$ \int_{v=0}^\pi \int_{u=v} ^{\pi+v} \vert \cos(u)\vert dudv$$ using the substitution $x=u-v, y=v$.

Please explain with fig. I saw in [value of $ \int_0^\pi \int_0 ^\pi \vert \cos(x+y)\vert dxdy$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615767/value-of-int-0-pi-int-0-pi-vert-cosxy-vert-dxdy)

Please help me to understand the limit.
I understand the following:
Jacobian =1

(0,0) in xy-plane corresponds to (0,0) in u-v plane

x-axis in xy-plane corresponds to u axis u-v plane

y-axis in xy-plane corresponds to (0,0) in u=v line in u-v plane

$x=\pi$ line corresponds to $u=\pi+ v$, $v\in (0,\pi)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain is $0<x<\pi$ and $0<y<\pi$. If you perform the change $x=u-v$ and $y=v$, from the second condition is clear (or not?) that $\boxed{0<v<\pi}$.

Let's go with first condition $0<x<\pi$:

- $0<x\longrightarrow 0<u-v$ an then $\boxed{v<u}$
- $x<\pi\longrightarrow u-v<\pi$ an then $\boxed{u<\pi+v}$

Then your new domain in $u,v$ variables is $0<v<\pi$ and $v<u<\pi+v$

[image]

Comment: Then what wound be the figure

Comment: New domain is the region between the two parallel lines $u=v$ and $u=v+\pi$ from $v=0$ to $v=\pi$.

Comment: you understand?

Comment: Yes... but plot of the line u=pi+v is correct? It goes through (0, -pi) and (pi, 0)

Comment: Then, can you value my answer?

Comment: The line $u=\pi+v$ is correct: goes from $(0,\pi)$ to $(\pi,2\pi)$

Comment: But u=π+v is a line joining (0, -pi) and (pi, 0)?

Comment: u=π+v will be parallel to u=v and below u=v?

Comment: I'm sorry but if you want people waste time in your questions at least you must to evaluate it.

Comment: Sorry... but as domain in u,v variables is 0<v<π and v<u<π+v, we have u>v. As 2>1, (2,1) lies in the domain. But as per your plot (2,1) does not lie in your domain. Sorry .. your first part helped me to understand but the plot is not seems to me correct. Thank you.

Comment: I thought it should not be specified, but the domain I have drawn are points of the form $(v, u)$ (abscissa axis  $0V$)

Comment: Ok.... I thought (u, v), then it's ok.

Comment: I answered your question, I draw the region, I replied your comments...I'm just asking you to value my time / effort. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. Accepted already your answer.